# Does useOptimistic works only with forms?

Tags: reactjs

I use simple SPA app created from default `react-ts` template `pnpm create vite react19-useOptimistic --template react-ts`.

Full code is here - https://github.com/acherkashin/react19-useOptimistic/blob/main/src/App.tsx.

React Version:"react": "18.3.0-canary-bb0944fe5-20240313"

I have the following form. `useOptimistic` work fine here.

```
const AddToCartForm = ({ title, addToCart, optimisticAddToCart }: AddToCartFormProps) => {
  const formAction = async (formData: FormData) => {
    const itemId = String(formData.get('itemID'));
    optimisticAddToCart({ id: itemId, title, pending: true });
    try {
      await addToCart(itemId, title);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      // show error notification
    }
  };

  return (
    <form action={formAction}>
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      <input type="hidden" name="itemID" value={crypto.randomUUID()} />
      <button type="submit">Add to Cart</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

However, if I replace `form` with `div` and will move `formAction` to `onClick` of `button`, optimistic updates will not happen.

```
const AddToCartForm = ({ title, addToCart, optimisticAddToCart }: AddToCartFormProps) => {
  const formAction = async () => {
    const itemId = crypto.randomUUID();
    optimisticAddToCart({ id: itemId, title, pending: true });
    try {
      await addToCart(itemId, title);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      // show error notification
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      <button onClick={() => formAction()}>Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Is it expected behavior? Or am I doing something wrong? Should I be able to use `useOptimistic` outside the forms?

Comment: I run into the same issue. It indeed seems to be the case that creating an optimistic update only works from a form action. It’s incredibly frustrating this isn’t documented anywhere (although to be fair, it’s part of canary version of React).